# HttpMessageInvoker is ignoring Connection Timeout

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, httpclient

I have initialized an HttpMessageInvoker with a SocketsHttpHandler, and set these properties to two minutes (120 seconds):

```
ConnectTimeout
KeepAlivePingTimeout
PooledConnectionIdleTimeout
```

I also set a CancellationToken to 120 seconds to cancel.

Here is the call to SendAsync:

```
destinationResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(destinationRequest, requestTimeoutToken);
```

And here is where the HttpMessageInvoker is created:

```
var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler
            {
                UseProxy = false,
                AllowAutoRedirect = false,
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.None,
                UseCookies = false, EnableMultipleHttp2Connections = true, 
                MaxConnectionsPerServer = 5000, 
            };

handler.ConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
handler.KeepAlivePingTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
handler.PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);

return new HttpMessageInvoker(new ActivityPropagationHandler(handler), disposeHandler: true);
```

However, when I call HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync to a URL that is unreachable, it times out after 21.2 seconds every time, instead of after 120 seconds as expected.  This application is running on Windows 11/Windows Server 2022.

I need it to timeout after 120 seconds.  How do I fix this?  I am using .NET 6.0.  I would have expected these timeouts to work as expected, however they seem to have no effect.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could we get a code fragment to help here? It's a bit hard to decipher the actual issue as it may not be happening at the HttpMessageInvoker but something else in the entire config.

Comment: @MelroyCoelho Sure - I just added some code snippets, hope this helps

Comment: Does this `httpClient` refer to the `HttpMessageInvoker` object? And what is `ActivityPropagationHandler`? Have you checked the stack of the timeout exception?

Comment: Agree with Shingo, its not the HttpClientHandler that is being called here but the ActivityPropagationHandler so is it overriding properties that would generally be set for the HttpHandler causing this issue?